# MATLAB permission denied to access files from C (OS partition)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, installation, installshield

I created an installer with Installshield for my MATLAB GUI. Installer copies all files of my program to `c:/Program files/Program_name`. When I run it from shortcut, an error appears that `can't overwrite some file`. I think this is a permission error because my program is in OS partition. I have some functions like `mget` , `mput` and `fprintf` for some text files in that directory and some times my software download some files from `FTP` and copy them in discoursed directory.

When you copy some codes that have functions like these and run your code from `C:/ (OS partition)`, you have this problem (without using any installer). I need an automatic solution because this program is going to install on some computers.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Write to MyDocuments instead (e.g. appdata) - that's the one place where the user is guaranteed to have write permissions.

Comment: that's true but I think maybe there is a more general solution for this problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jonas. How can I find my document folder from MATLAB ? Because we have something like this : `C:\Users\Username\Documents` and username is different in every computer.

Comment: This may help http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15885-get-user-home-directory

Comment: Thanks.Temporary solution :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write to MyDocuments instead (e.g. appdata) - that's the one place where the user is guaranteed to have write permissions.

(Jonas comment. Thank you for your answer)